# Error CORS entre mi API y frontend, Como solucionarlo?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy desarrollando una api con php para una sistema web, utilizo la libreria [Flight](https://flightphp.com/) para desarrollarla. He configurado en la api los headers:

```
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header("Allow: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, UPDATE, OPTIONS");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, UPDATE, OPTIONS");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
  header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

Sin embargo al momento de hacer una peticion fetch() a la url de la api me arroja un error de CORS el cual dice lo siguiente:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost/api/api/v1/1254652f4/dashboard/' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Dicho sea de paso realizo la misma peticion con [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) y no da ningun error.
Tengo de igual manera un archivo .htaccess en el cual estan las siguientes lineas:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

La peticion fetch la realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
 var myHeaders = new Headers();
 myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer");
 myHeaders.append("x-api-key", "$2y$15$eXAElFJHbJYZ1Hj.uY7IWubUyulOSo68tXEicCv/MV7Nax816RmGC");
 myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

 var requestOptions = {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: myHeaders,
   redirect: 'follow'
 };

 fetch("http://localhost/api/api/v1/1254652f4/dashboard/", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

E intentado de igual manera agregar los headers en este archivo más sin embargo el resultado es el mismo, espero y puedan apoyarme a encontrar o a saber la solución. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Postman no sirve como comprobacion de CORS, los navegadores chequean CORS, postman no.

Comment: Si eso lo entiendo, lo que necesito saber es como puedo solucionar este error: `Access to fetch at 'https://localhost/api/api/v1/1254652f4/dashboard/' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

Comment: Cuando haces la petición desde que url la haces??

Comment: Eh editado la pregunta, para responderle @Yussef

Comment: No me entendiste, esa aplicación que realiza el fetch ¿que url tiene?

Comment: Básicamente si es distinto a localhost o estas utilizando otro puerto

Comment: @Yussef La peticion la estoy realizando desde http://localhost el puerto por defecto es 80

Comment: Esas cabeceras las envias en cual ruta? Debes tener en cuenta que en tu servidor (en este caso en la api) debes tener para esa ruta los métodos GET y OPTIONS activados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es en el preflight:

Una petición preflight: se efectua antes de enviar la petición (POST,GET,PUT, etc) para comprobar las opciones disponibles.

puedes documentarte [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

Aqui tienes como lo he solucionado

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
    header('Content-Length: 0');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    die();
}

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

como nota: es importante el `die();` dentro del if para que el preflight finalice.

Comment: En efecto el problema era el mensionado eh aplicado los headers requeridos en mi api y ha fucionado correctamente ¡muchas gracias por el apoyo @W Aleman!!!

Answer (score -2):

Basicamente ese problema de **CORS** es por que en tu API no tienen configurado tu **dominio** donde está el front como permitido, intenta modificar tu API para agregar el dominio de localhost a la lista o en su defecto, si estás probando solamente, podrías permitir todos los dominios solo mientras haces pruebas.

Por cierto, Postman se salta éstas validaciones, es por eso que en ahí funciona correctamente!

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]